# Are there 2 types of double-quotes in R? My double quotes look slanted and are giving an error message

Tags: r, double-quotes

I am using the statement in R:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\carl\\Documents\\research")
```

to set the working directory.  It worked fine when I pasted the statement from someone else's R script but I received an error message:

> Error: unexpected input in "setwd("".

when I entered the command directly or when I copied it from my script in a Word file.

It seems to be related to the fact that the double-quotes that I typed (that don't work) look a little slanted while the double-quotes in the pasted text (that work fine) look like they're straight up and down.  Is there something I can do to type plain looking double-quotes instead of slanted double-quotes?

Comment: you need forward slashes in R. Use either `/` or `\\\`. see if that fixes it

Comment: Normally the reverse is true; copy-paste from other sources causes issues. What editor are you using?

Comment: @neilfws You edited vital information out of the question.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm pretty sure that I typed two backward slashes when I typed the question but it appears that the double-backslashes were changed to a single backslash when the questions posted.  In any case, the R command that I am trying to use contains double  backslashes.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen You're right! Word wasn't mentioned in the original. I think it was added just as I was editing for format and got missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word automatically replaces your double quotes with so-called smart quotes or curly quotes.

You need to use the regular/straight double quotes (`"`) in r.

[This support article](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/smart-quotes-in-word-702fc92e-b723-4e3d-b2cc-71dedaf2f343) explains how you can disable the automatic smart quote replacement in Word. In fairness though, Word is probably not the... um... ideal code editor.

Comment: Thank you -- I think your answer will solve my problem.  Much appreciated!